# Why do the LEDs flash in the attached circuit diagram when adjust the variable resistor

Tags: led, capacitor, circuit-analysis

My son is studying the attached circuit. He found that LEDs will either grow consistently or flash when if adjust the variable resistor. However, we cannot figure out how this happen. How does the current flow? Could anyone explain how does the circuit work? Thank you.

[image: Circuit Diagram]

Comment: How much do you know about electronics, generally, and BJTs and LEDs, specifically? What ***can*** you already work out?

Comment: The \$470\:\mu\text{F}\$ cap eventually charges up near the supply voltage (and mostly stays there except for a slight drop during each LED pulse.) The \$10\:\mu\text{F}\$ cap has one side tied close to (-) side (if you've set the potentiometer to a low enough value) while the other side of that cap also now charges towards the supply voltage via the \$100\:\text{k}\Omega\$ resistor. At some point, the base of the NPN is brought high enough that it turns on (the LED in its emitter makes this a higher voltage than expected.)

Comment: When that happens, the NPN turns on, thus turning on its LED, while pulling that LED current out from the PNP base. That fact turns the PNP on, as well, causing its collector to pull hard and upward on the "closer-to-ground" end of the \$10\:\mu\text{F}\$ cap. That causes the NPN base end of that capacitor to be even more positive causing the NPN to activate still more (positive feedback.) Quite soon, though, that cap has not only discharged but has acquired enough of a negative voltage that the NPN turns off and, after some recharging, the cycle repeats.

Comment: I'd recommend inserting a resistor, between \$10\:\Omega\$ and \$22\:\Omega\$, in series with the "37/36" LED, though. Just to help limit the current pulse a little.

Comment: Hi Jonk, thanks very much. Your explanation helps a lot. We understand now. I am not good at this aspect. Just my kid has an experiment kit and built the above circuit. However, I have no idea how this works and am not able to explain to him

Comment: Well, hopefully what I've written can help a little. It is "kind of tricky" because of how it grabs the low end of the \$10\:\mu\text{F}\$ capacitor and yanks it upward each cycle in order to re-inforce (positive feedback) things when the NPN finally starts to turn on. Some imagination is needed for that. But blinking circuits like this pretty much have to rely on some trick like that. So it's not unusual. Just tricky.